# Exit from a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, exit

I have some loop and a condition. If codition is matched then I want to stop or exit from the stored procedure. How to do that?

```
while @@fetch_status=0
    begin
        if x=0
            'exit stored procedure
    end
```

Comment: Which type and version of Sql of you using?  Sql Server, Oracle, MySql?  The @@fetch_status does suggest sql server.

Comment: accept answer it it work for you

Answer (score 12):

if you are using Microsoft Sql Server than you can use `Return` Statement

```
while @@fetch_status=0 begin if x=0 return; end
```

Comment: thx for the answer..can i asked u more question.hehe..since im new in sql...thx b4...
how about if i hv 2 loop
while @@fetch_status=0
begin 
    set y=y+1
    set x=0
     while @@fetch_status=0
     begin
        x=y+1
        if y = 5
        'exit the second do while and back to the first do while --> y=y+1
     end

end

Comment: yes in that case you must use goto statement suggested in below answer

Answer (score 4):

By `@@fetch_status` it looks like your inside a cursor loop so I would **not** return at that point as you will skip tidying up after yourself.

```
...
if x=0
  GOTO DONE
...
/* at the end of the sp */
DONE:
  CLOSE @your_cur
  DEALLOCATE @your_cur
```

Answer (score 2):

try use return

```
while @@fetch_status=0
    begin
        if x=0
            return
    end
```