# How can I exit an inner loop and continue an outer loop?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, cursors

This is a follow-up to [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2728580/exit-from-a-stored-procedure) (Thanks for the answer, BTW!)

If I have two loops:

```
while @@fetch_status=0
begin 
    set y=y+1
    set x=0
     while @@fetch_status=0
     begin
        x=y+1
        if y = 5
        'exit the second do while and back to the first do while --> y=y+1
     end
end
```

...how can I exit from the inner loop and continue the outer (see comment)?

Comment: @leonita: Welcome to StackOverflow! People reading this question have two problems: They do not know your previous question, and they cannot read this one because it is poorly formatted. If you have a simple follow-up question to another question of yours, add a comment there. If you feel that this is a separate question, make sure that the question is clear without knowing the other question. And please edit your question to format your code (select and press Ctrl+K). Use preview to check how your question looks like.

Comment: Please take more care with how you write questions. This is almost unreadable. Bear in mind that StackOverflow requires you to use an excellent formatting mechanism when writing posts. I suggest you take a look at it.: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: also, rather than using cursors always try first to take a set based approach

Comment: If this is homework please tag it as such.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for [BREAK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181271.aspx)

Books online is a great resource for TSQL

Answer (score 1):

WHy are you looping? In general looping and cursors are a bad thing in SQL server which is optimized to handle sets fo data not row by row processing. It is very possible that you don't need or want a loop at all.